# SSRS Report Expressions: SWITCH, InStr and LCase

Tags: regex, reporting-services

I have `InStr` function that seems not to match when numbers are at the beginning of the search string.

```
=Switch(
InStr(LCase(Fields!Frequency.Value), "3 times a day") >= 1, "TID",
InStr(LCase(Fields!Frequency.Value), "4 times a day") >= 1, "QID"
)
```

If I remove either the 3 or 4 from `3 times a day` or `4 times a day` respectively, the `InStr` function works.  How do I search for a string that begins with numbers?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code seems all right. What error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

couldn't you use 
contains or indexof functions instead like:

```
LCase(Fields!Frequency.Value).Contains("3 times a day") , "TID"
```

or

```
LCase(Fields!Frequency.Value).IndexOf("3 times a day")>= 0 , "TID"
```

i tried a sample and your code should work.
maybe you have a double space somewhere try adding a replace to the formula

```
LCase(replace(Fields!Frequency.Value,"  "," ")
```

Comment: I tried both of these functions too and both don't work. I can do it other ways but for design reasons I want the logic to stay within this area of the report.  Its odd all three expressions functions don't work.

Comment: may be there is a double space or something.